# System running in low graphics mode and Ubuntu is not booting

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

Ubuntu is not booting. The system was running in low graphics mode and not detecting the hardware after I accidentally deleted the xorg.conf.failsafe file.

After reinstalling xorg the boot page is a black screen with `/dev/sda5 clean, 353237/2199344 files, 4476772/8782848 blocks` and my device doesn't go beyond this point. What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the xorg.conf.failsafe file made the system unbootable, so restore it by reinstalling X.Org Window System (*xorg*). After that you may also need to reinstall the Nvidia graphics driver, but first of all reinstall xorg.

1. Open a text-only virtual console by using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.
2. At the `login:` prompt type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. At the `Password:` prompt type your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Now you are logged in to a virtual console, and you can run terminal commands from the console. Run the following commands.

   ```
    sudo apt-get install --reinstall xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-video-nouveau 
    sudo reboot
   ```
5. After the system reboots comment if anything is not working properly, especially the Nouveau open source graphics driver, the Nvidia graphics driver or if you get a low graphics mode error screen again. Run the following commands either from the virtual console (accessed by steps 1-3) or from the terminal and comment about any errors you receive.

   ```
    sudo apt-get update  
    sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```
6. Run the following commands from the virtual console (accessed by steps 1-3) and comment about any errors you receive.

   ```
    sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-vesa    
    sudo reboot
   ```
7. The proprietary NVIDIA drivers are still not supported under Wayland yet in Ubuntu 17.10. When you want to install and use the NVIDIA drivers, you have to select *Ubuntu on Xorg* on the GDM login screen to enter the X session. Then open the terminal and type:

   ```
    sudo ubuntu-drivers install  
    sudo reboot
   ```

   The `install` option of `ubuntu-drivers` installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies.

Comment: Now it does not boot beyond the given screen (the photo is updated)... What should i do?