# Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS with NVidia drivers are not used with Wayland (Ubuntu on Wayland) but are used in X11 (Ubuntu)

Tags: nvidia, xorg, opengl, mesa

I installed the NVidia drivers on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Native Linux) and everything went smoothly.  The drivers work just fine under X11.  However, under Wayland, they are not used and instead, I get:

`Graphics      llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7, 256 bits).`

In my own OpenGL application, I get:

```
Vendor:       Mesa/X.org
Renderer:     llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7, 256 bits)
Version:      4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1-22.04.3
```

Are the NVidia drivers not supported under Wayland?  Is there any way around it?  I am trying to beta test my OpenGL application on Wayland.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System running in low graphics mode and Ubuntu is not booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965945/system-running-in-low-graphics-mode-and-ubuntu-is-not-booting)

Comment: Does this mean the proprietary NVidia drivers don't work under Wayland?

Comment: It seems they are not actually supported.  If someone can figure how to make them work, please let me know.